# how to stop inline-block whitespace being rendered in the browser

Tags: css, whitespace, multiple-columns

Roughly speaking, attempting to build a four-column layout, I've got this HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>A column</div>
    <div>A column</div>
    <div>A column</div>
    <div>A column</div>
</div>
```

And I've got this CSS:

```
div {
    background: #ccc;
}

div div {
    background: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}
```

-> [Fiddle me this](http://jsfiddle.net/v4WC7/) <-

When rendered in the browser (Currently, I have been testing with Chrome only) the whitespace between the nested div elements (in this example the whitespace is caused by line breaks) is rendered, thus throwing my layout out.

Clearly, I can float my nested divs...

```
div {
    background: #ccc;
}

div div {
    background: #eee;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

-> [Fiddle me that](http://jsfiddle.net/s2rJW/) <-

But then my container div collapses and I don't want to have to have to use CSS clearfix hacks or extra HTML to open it back up.

Alternatively I can modify my HTML such that the whitespace is removed...

```
<div><div>A column</div><div>A column</div><div>A column</div><div>A column</div></div>
```

but that makes it hard to work with. The alternative of breaking the tags so that it becomes more readable somehow leaves me feeling dirty...

```
<div>
    <div>A column</
    div><div>A column</
    div><div>A column</
    div><div>A column</div>
</div>
```

I've found a [resource](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) or [two](http://www.lifeathighroad.com/web-development/css-web-development/inline-block-whitespace-workaround/) (I failed to find anything on SO) but I don't really like any of the solutions - they are all workarounds, which I will entertain if I must but surely there's an alternative?

So my question(s)... is there a cross-browser, w3c-compliant, non-javascript, hack-free, tidy HTML, bombproof way of preventing HTML whitespace from being rendered in the browser whilst using `display:inline-block`? Or is there an alternative to inline-block that can be used that has no unpleasant side effects?

**EDIT**

Assuming that this is genuinely impossible, the best solution would be something that required no addition HTML markup and 'flexible' CSS. In other words, a webmaster could edit the HTML as normal without consideration of breaking the layout, and the CSS (hacked or otherwise) will accommodate the webmaster's amends without having to be amended itself.

**MY "WORKAROUND"**

Well, it looks like something's got to give. In my situation it is more important to have HTML that doesn't require extra markup so the best solution is to work in a CSS hack that "just works" invisibly. The solution is to float the nested divs and add a hack...

```
div div {
    float: left;
}

div::before,
div::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

div::after {
    clear: both;
}

div {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

...which is a derivation of a fix I've been using for some time and was hoping to avoid. This succint version of the fix was found [on this site](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

So now every single div in the markup has got the clearfix hack applied to it whether it needs it or not. I'm yet to learn if this has any bad side-effects by being applied to *all* divs - I look forward to debugging and fixing when any problems surface ;-)

Comment: If you really want to meet all of these criteria (cross-browser, w3c-compliant, non-javascript, hack-free, tidy HTML, bombproof way) – no, there is not.

Comment: The solution proposed, as you suggest on http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ with giving the block a font-size:0 and the element the font-size you want, seems to e a good solution : no html strange code etc.. i'd use that

Comment: in my experience that has been the case. If that is a given then perhaps we should look at a way of checking as many of those boxes as possible?

Comment: @audre7 You either need to rely on pixel-based font-sizing on the child-divs – which is not nice, or use relative EMs – which are not supported in IE8 and below. (In my opinion, relying on REMs would be the best of these two worlds)

Comment: The dirty feeling from breaking up tags is the closest thing to a clean solution I've seen. Fiddling with margins and font sizes can have undesirable side-effects. Removing the whitespace has none (other than that dirty dirty feeling) ;)

Comment: Your floating method is the one to use, but you MUST clear your floats before the end of the containing element. `<span style="display: block; clear: both"></span>` should do it.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: In his question he points out clearly, why and that he doesn't want to use floats and clearfixes.

Comment: Then he's actively rejecting a solution that is widely accepted as fine. Even using an ::after pseudo selector would fix it, and is not a hack. If you use floats, you must clear them.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks That is not the case. He rejects a solution that is not widely accepted. People don't want to use hacks and unintentional use of css techniques.

Comment: @kleinfreund yep, you right, i didn't try with em, and it doesn't work ... use the display:table & table-cell ? but not supported (unless plugin) in ie ?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks, very true, however, I am wanting to avoid floating because the CSS I am developing will be used by people with less experience than us. I don't want to have to explain why they need to start adding extra markup to get the layout working and why it doesn't simply "work". Inevitably I will be called in to fix layouts that they can't sort out themselves.

Comment: @andre7 See this article by Nicolas Gallagher for a relatively new and nice little clearfixing method – sure it's still a hack. http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: @Doug: Good call on trying to simplify things for those with less experience, you could insert the clearfix with jQuery to "just make it work" or use an ::after pseudo element. Also, if you don't explain, how will they learn? :D http://jsfiddle.net/s2rJW/3/ for an easy way to clear, that the other users don't necessarily need to know about.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks I guess I can use jQuery to shove a clearfix class on every single element... that could work... apart of JS-disabled browsers :( What do you mean about the ::after psudoelement? I've been fiddling with this in CSS attempting to get something working but I haven't had any joy yet.

Comment: @Doug: Read the article I posted some comments ago. There is an easy clearfix, who doesn't need additional markup in your HTML.

Comment: @kleinfreund - I've been using something like that for years - admittedly an old-fashioned version of the same trick. I even call it .cf too :) It has been my favoured solution.

Comment: I linked to an update jsfiddle, it uses a pseudo element created by CSS (or something akin to that) that in essence makes the element auto clear itself.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - I've just been working on exactly the same solution! ;-)

Comment: I've gone with the cleafix solution in a bit of a 'blunderbuss' approach. I've edited my OP to reflect this. Thanks all! :-)

Comment: minifiy ur html. that space will get removed.

Answer (score 7):

You provided nearly all possible solutions to this big layout question. I just want to point out my preferred solution.

### Set font-size to the parent to 0 and resetting it again with REM's.

You'll have no trouble with your code and layout if there is no additional text inside the parent div (not the child divs).

REM's (Relative EM's) are not relative to the font-size of the parent elements (like normal EM's are), but relative to the root element of your document – the `html` element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">column 1</div>
    <div class="child">column 2</div>
    <div class="child">column 3</div>
    <div class="child">column 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    font-size: 1em;
}

.parent {
    font-size: 0;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px; /* Add pixel-based font-size to support IE8 and below */
    font-size: 1rem; /* Don't use rem along with the font-shorthand to avoid problems in IE9/10 - see note below */
    width: 25%;
}
```

**No Browser support:**

- IE8 and below: Add pixel-based font-size to make it work.
- IE9/10: not working with `font`-shorthand; use `font-size` instead!
- (Opera Mini & iOS 3.2)

Answer (score 2):

> is there a ... way of preventing HTML whitespace from being rendered in the browser whilst using display:inline-block?

Yes, there are several ways. None of them really meet your criteria of 'hack-free' and 'tidy', but they do work.

- Reformat ('minify') your code so that it doesn't have any white space between the elements.
  This is probably the most hack-free and cross-browser solution. It isn't necessarily tidy though, and it means you're fixing your layout by adjusting the HTML rather than the CSS, which isn't ideal. But it does work well. If you want to keep your code readable, you could use HTML comments so you can keep the gaps but without them being in the DOM:

  ```
     <div>block 1</div><!--
  --><div>block 2</div><!--
  --><div>block 3</div>
  ```

  Still not ideal, but more readable than a massive single line of code.
- Set the `font-size` to zero for the container, and back to full size again for the blocks.
  This works really well. It's a pure CSS solution and easy to do. The down side is that it can be difficult to work with if you've got relative font sizes (ie setting back to `14px` is fine, but setting to `1em` won't work because `1em` of the previous font size of zero is still zero).
- Set a `1em` negative margin to close the gap.
  This also works pretty well, but can be imprecise.

> Or is there an alternative to inline-block that can be used that has no unpleasant side effects?

- There's always `float:left`. But that's got a whole range of different issues of its own. If you're using `inline-block`, the odds are good it's because you don't want to use floats.
- Use `position:absolute` and do the layout manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the float method you described in your question, but you didn't clear your floats, which is why the container collapses.

A good method is to use an `::after` pseudo element attache to the container element to "auto-clear" itself:

```
 div:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s2rJW/3/

Comment: Refer to http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ if you want to know more about this clearfix method.

Answer (score 0):

When i saw your "workaround" i was thinking: Why don't you use a `<table>`?

And then i figured this out:

```css
div {
  background: #ccc;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
div div {
  background: #eee;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>A column</div>
  <div>A column</div>
  <div>A column</div>
  <div>A column</div>
</div>
```